# ng-repeat filter by array of object only by specific properties

Tags: angularjs, search, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have an array of objects that I am ng-repeating over. I have a search box to filter results. Each object contains a variety of properties, some of which aren't relevant to the search filter. I'd like to limit the filter to only 2 of the properties. In the example below, I'd like to ignore the 'gender' property and only filter by 'name' or 'phone'.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example52-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="">
    <div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276', gender: 'male'},
                           {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY', gender: 'female'},
                           {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', gender: 'male'},
                           {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', gender: 'male'},
                           {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', gender: 'female'},
                           {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678', gender: 'female'}]"></div>

  Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
  <table id="searchTextResults">
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a custome filter:-

```
<table id="searchTextResults">
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:search">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  $scope.search = function (row) {
        return (angular.lowercase(row.name).indexOf($scope.searchText || '') !== -1 || angular.lowercase(row.phone).indexOf($scope.searchText || '') !== -1);
    };
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HwjrrTUnjxUmxxlEfv2p?p=preview)

Comment: thanks this works, it would be nice to do it the html but it doesn't seem like there is an easy way.